# Slider and Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make a very simple Shiny application. Until now, I have implemented some basic staff, such as selecting charts from the drop-down menu and selecting values with a slider. Below you can see my code :

````
---
title: "Test App"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)


# Data Set 1

df<-data.frame( cyl=c("4","6","8"),
                Multiplier=c(2,4,6)
                )

# Data Set 2

df1 <- mtcars
df1$cyl <- as.factor(df1$cyl)


```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
useShinyjs(rmd = TRUE)

selectInput("clusterNum",
  label = h4("Charts"),
  choices = list("Chart1" = "Chart1", "Chart2" = "Chart2"),
  selected = "Chart1"
)

sidebarPanel(sliderInput("integer", "Integer:",
                  min = 0, max = 8,
                  value = 1),)


```


Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart

```{r}

# First chart
Chart1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()

# Second chart
Chart2 <- reactive({
  dplyr::left_join(df, df1, by = c("cyl" = "cyl")) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(mpg_new = (mpg * Multiplier * input$integer)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = mpg_new)) +
    geom_point()
})

# Visualization of the selected chart
renderPlot({
  switch(input$clusterNum,
    "Chart1" = Chart1,
    "Chart2" = Chart2()
  )
})


# Second chart data
Chart2_dat <- reactive({
  dplyr::left_join(df, df1, by = c("cyl" = "cyl")) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(mpg_new = (mpg * Multiplier * input$integer))
})

# Second chart
Chart2 <- reactive({
  Chart2_dat() %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = mpg_new)) +
    geom_point()
})

# Visualization of the selected chart
renderPlot({
  switch(input$clusterNum,
    "Chart1" = Chart1,
    "Chart2" = Chart2()
  )
})

```
````

But here, a problem arose. Namely, instead of seeing the slider in normal size, it is displayed in miniature, and the values cannot be selected accordingly. Can someone help me fix the size of the slider to look like the image shown below?

[image]

Comment: Get rid of the `sidebarPanel`. You already added a sidebar via `Column {.sidebar}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width = 12` argument in your `sidebarPanel`:

```
sidebarPanel(sliderInput("integer", "Integer:",
                         min = 0, max = 8,
                         value = 1),
             width = 12)
```